# My android app started crashing occasionally when I press one of the 4 buttons after I implemented the code to generate another equation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

Im making an app that has a timer that counts down from 30s. You get an equation with 4 button with 1 of them being correct. A score is kept track of and a new equation is generated every time you press a button. Im not done with the code yet, but the general concept works. I dont have an end after the timer ends etc. I'm just wondering if anyone can look at my code and see why half of the time it works and the other half it crashes. Don't judge my bad Coding concepts xD. It only crashes sometimes when i press the buttons after i implemented the code to refresh the equation generated and the random numbers on the buttons

---

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int sum;
    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
    public Button button3;
    public Button button4;
    public Button[] answerButtons;
    public int randButton;
    public int counter;
    public int amountCorrect;
    public TextView scoreTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        answerButtons = new Button[]{button1, button2, button3, button4};
        scoreTextView = findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);
        counter = 0;
        amountCorrect = 0;

        runEquation();//runs all the methods to create an equation and the numbers stored in the buttons
        timerCountDown();
    }//onCreate()

    public void runEquation(){
        generateEquation();
        getButtonNumbers();
        setRandomButtonAnswer();
    }//runEquation()

    public void timerCountDown(){
        TextView timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

        int lengthOfTime = 30; //amount of time for the timer in seconds

        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(lengthOfTime*1000, 1000) {//*1000 because it is measure in milliseconds
            @Override
            public void onTick(long timeLeft) {
                timerTextView.setText(Long.toString(timeLeft/1000) + 's');//'s' represents seconds
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
    }//timerCountDown()

    public void generateEquation(){//generates 2 random numbers between 3 and 15 and adds them together in variable sum
        int numOne = randomNumber(3, 15); //3 is min number, 15 is max number
        int numTwo = randomNumber(3, 15); //3 is min number, 15 is max number
        sum = numOne + numTwo;//public int to check with the equations generated by the buttons

        displayEquation(numOne, numTwo, sum);
    }//generateEquation()

    public int randomNumber(int min, int max){//generates a random number between min and max parameters
        int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * (max-min) + min);//generates a random number between between the min and max parameters
        return randNum;
    }//randomNumber

    public void displayEquation(int numOne, int numTwo, int sum){
        TextView equationTextView = findViewById(R.id.equationTextView);
        equationTextView.setText(numOne + " + " + numTwo + " = ?");
    }//displayEquation()


    public void getButtonNumbers(){//sets the text of each of the buttons to a number generated from generateButtonNumber()
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            answerButtons[i].setText(Integer.toString(generateButtonNumber(i)));
        }//end of for
    }//getButtonNumbers()

    public int generateButtonNumber(int index){//generates a random number between 3 and 15
        int min = 3;
        int max = 15;

        int randNum = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        return randNum;
    }//generateButtonNumber()

    public void setRandomButtonAnswer(){//randomly overwrites one of the 4 buttons as the correct answer
        int min = 1;
        int max = 5;//not inclusive (1-4)

        randButton = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        answerButtons[randButton].setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }//setRandomButtonAnswer

    public void checkAnswer(View v){
        Button answerButton = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
        int answer = Integer.parseInt(answerButton.getText().toString());

        if(answer == sum){
            correctAnswer();
        }
        else{
            wrongAnswer();
        }
    }//checkAnswer()

    public void correctAnswer(){
        counter++;
        amountCorrect++;
        scoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(amountCorrect) + " / " + Integer.toString(counter));
        runEquation();
    }//correctAnswer()

    public void wrongAnswer(){
        counter++;
        scoreTextView.setText(Integer.toString(amountCorrect) + " / " + Integer.toString(counter));
        runEquation();
    }//wrongAnswer()
}```
````

Comment: Posting the stack trace will help in determining what is wrong.

Comment: What is a stack trace? Sorry I’m new to this

Comment: Check your logcat include the crash details. you can see android studio bottom.
Watch youtube videos. Debugging skill most important

Comment: Please give your XML code, I will try to recreate this and see where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is in the following method:

```
public void setRandomButtonAnswer(){//randomly overwrites one of the 4 buttons as the correct answer
    int min = 1;
    int max = 5;//not inclusive (1-4)

    randButton = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    answerButtons[randButton].setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}//setRandomButtonAnswer
```

You are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.setRandomButtonAnswer(MainActivity.java:104)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.runEquation(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
```

This should be changed to:

```
int max = 4;
```

So, the new method should be:

```
public void setRandomButtonAnswer(){//randomly overwrites one of the 4 buttons as the correct answer
    int min = 1;
    int max = 4;//not inclusive (1-4)

    randButton = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    answerButtons[randButton].setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}//setRandomButtonAnswer
```

Hopefully this fixes it.